# Is the open keyword a trait / mixin?

Tags: ruby, scala, f#, functional-programming

When I use the open keyword in F#

```ml
module AnotherModule

open myFSharpModule
```

Can this be thought of as a mixin in Ruby or a trait in Scala? I was thinking the other day how i wish that F# had these features, but then it occurred to me that the `open` keyword may be the same thing. In a way, it just copies the referenced module into the module you are defining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In F#, `open` is just [importing declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393787.aspx) to be accessible from the scope you're importing them.

It does not make those declarations part of your module, it's just so that you can reference them without qualification from *within* your module.

The equivalent in Scala is `import`, in Ruby it's `require`.

Comment: i guess i wouldn't actually be able to call those functions from outside ``myFSharpModule`` in my example so it wouldn't be the same as a trait.

Comment: ok, i'm going to ask another question for faking that functionality